# Video freezes when Admob's ad load Flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, video-streaming, ads

Hy there everyone. I'm new to Flutter. I want to implement Admob ads in my app. Basically my app is about live streaming of News.
Whenever the ads load the audio works fine but there is a lag in video.
Can anyone help me with this??

Hy there everyone. I'm new to Flutter. I want to implement Admob ads in my app. Basically my app is about live streaming of News.
Whenever the ads load the audio works fine but there is a lag in video.
Can anyone help me with this??

Hy there everyone. I'm new to Flutter. I want to implement Admob ads in my app. Basically my app is about live streaming of News.
Whenever the ads load the audio works fine but there is a lag in video.
Can anyone help me with this??

```
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class StreamPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String channelURL;
  final String channelName;
  final String channelImage;
  StreamPlayer(
      {@required this.channelURL,
      @required this.channelName,
      @required this.channelImage});
  @override
  _StreamPlayerState createState() => _StreamPlayerState();
}

class _StreamPlayerState extends State<StreamPlayer> {
  BetterPlayerController _controller;
  BannerAd _bannerAd;
  bool _isBannerAdReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    playerConfig();
    getBanner();
  }

  playerConfig() {
    BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network, widget.channelURL,
        liveStream: true);
    _controller = BetterPlayerController(
        BetterPlayerConfiguration(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          autoDetectFullscreenDeviceOrientation: true,
          autoPlay: true,
        ),
        betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource);
  }

  getBanner() {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111', //Ad for Testing
      request: AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: AdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          setState(() {
            _isBannerAdReady = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
          _isBannerAdReady = false;
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );
    return _bannerAd.load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 45,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(0.3),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: widget.channelImage,
                    width: 25,
                    height: 25,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    placeholder: (context, url) => Icon(
                          Icons.image,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(
                          Icons.image,
                          size: 50,
                        )),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Text(widget.channelName,
                    style: GoogleFonts.teko(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor == Colors.blue
                          ? Colors.black54
                          : Colors.grey[50],
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: BetterPlayer(
                controller: _controller,
              ),
            ),
            _isBannerAdReady
                ? Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @KishanDhankecha I didn't get any solution. Please tell me if you find any.

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late. Just posting here to give refernce to others.
As I have wasted lots of hours due to it.

I was also facing the same issue when I was using video player with `google_mobile_ads` ad library

So I just switch to `native_admob_flutter` ad library on video page.
And it is working fine.

Hope this will save some hours of others.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I will try it sometime.

Comment: A weird bug, but works smoothly with the library native_admob_flutter